# Monty Hall exercise using random numbers

Tags: python

I think if I continue on the path I'm taking I'll eventually get it working, though I know it's unlikely the optimal solution but more importantly to me it won't have the random design I would want.

If I were to give each door a randint(1, 3), how could I make sure they don't end up the same number?

Another component of this currently I don't like and don't know how to get around is the choice() elif guess == 1 and guess == car: because it always prints door 2; how could I make it print door 2 or 3?

```python
import random

car = random.randint(1, 3)

print("Debug:" + str(car))


def prompt_guess():
    print("What door do you want?")
    guess = int(input())
    choice(guess)


def choice(guess):
    if guess == 1 and guess != car:
        next_door(guess)
    elif guess == 1 and guess == car:
        print("Opening door # 2")
    else:
        print("opening door # 3")


def next_door(guess):
    if guess == 2 and guess != car:
        print("Opening Door # 2")
        print("Here is a Goat")


# def stayNot(doorOpened):
    # print("Do you want to change doors or stay?")
    # decide = input()
    # print("The car was behind door # " + str(car))
    # if decide == "stay" and car != doorChosen:
    #     print("You lose because you didn't switch")

prompt_guess()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> give each door a randint(1, 3)

You're not? Only the "prize" is assigned a single "door value".

> how could I make sure they don't end up the same number?

If I understood correctly, your random number is fixed, and the user should guess. Since the "car" is fixed, and you get one number, then nothing will end up "the same".

If you just want to count the number of guesses until a correct answer, you can start with this

```
import random

car = random.randint(1, 3)
guesses = 0

guess = None
while guess != car:
    guess = int(input("What door do you want? "))
    guesses += 1
    
    print(f'Opening door #{guess}')
    if car == guess:
        print('You won!')
    else:
        print(f"Sorry! You've taken {guesses} guesses so far.")
```

Another approach would be to store a list of "doors", then randomly shuffle it and check where the goats are.

```
import random

def find_goats(lst):
  ''' return the indicies of the list where there are goats '''
  return [i for i,x in enumerate(lst) if x == 'goat']

prize = "car"
doors = ["goat", "goat", prize]
random.shuffle(doors)
goats = find_goats(doors)

guess = int(input('Which door? '))
print(f'There is a goat behind door {goats[-1]}')
goats.pop() # remove from list... assumes the user will not pick the door with the goat 
guess = int(input('Which door? (enter same number to keep choice) '))

if (guess-1) in goats:
    print('You found a goat!')    
else: 
    print(f'You won a {prize}!')
```

Comment: thanks, the list probably sounds like the better option. Haven't been introduced to that yet so I'll try it out.

The way the monty hall problem works is 3 doors, a goat behind two and car behind one - this changes each time. The user picks 1 door, a door with a goat is opened and then the user is given the option to decide whether they want to switch their original selection or stay with it and then that determines if they won or lost.

Comment: I'm familiar with the problem. The issue with your code (or my second soluiton) is that it only prompts for a single input. Using the `while` loop until they select the correct (closed) "door" seems to be what you want

Comment: Maybe? As I said, I'm very new to this so I'm trying to piece it together as a learning experience. I hope you don't feel I was condescending, I just wanted to make sure you knew what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Updated the second solution with what I think is more appropriate for what is being asked

Comment: yes, based on the test it looks like what I'm looking for. Thanks! Now to try to understand it, lol